# Composite Functions

Tags: functions

> If $f$ and $g$ are two functions, then the composite function $f \circ g$ is defined by
>
> $$f \circ g=f(g(x)).$$

This notation is compelling me to believe that the function $f \circ g$ is a function of the function $g(x)$. Is it correct to say that? Is $f \circ g$ a function of $g(x)$? If it  is incorrect to think that, where am I wrong then?

Comment: It is incorrect. $f\circ g$ depends only on $x$.

Comment: I would write $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$.  I think that's clearer if there are questions about the sort of thing expressed in this posting.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to see this notation is that, evaluated in $x$, $f\circ g$ takes the value
$$
f\circ g(x) = f(g(x))
$$
that is, $f$ evaluated in $g(x)$.

$f$ is not a function operating on functions, but on numbers.

This is why you note:

$$f:E\to F$$
meaning that $E$ is a way to associate an element of $F$ for each element of $F$.
An function operating on $\{\text{function }E\to F\}$  is necessarily another object.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:A\to B, f:B\to C$. Then, $f\circ g:A\to C$. This is also $f:(g(A))\to C$. So, if $x\in A$, then $f\circ g$ is a function of $x$, since $g(x)$ is a function of $x$. However, if we were to take $x\in B$, then $f\circ g=(f\circ g)(y)$, $y\in A$, is a function of $g(y)$ (note the abuse of notation), as $g(y)\in B$.